# Python3, cv2.setMouseCallback() and cv2.MouseCallback() parameter void* userdata

Tags: python, opencv

My python3 program uses OpenCV4, (cv2) to apply a series of masks to an image.  In main, I have a string myMask initially set to the string 'none'.  I want to pass this variable into my mouse event handlers.  Each event handler is tied to a window that displays one of the black and white mask images and has a parameter string that ends as  ..., void* user data).  The event handler responds to an EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN.  The selected event handler then changes the user data parameter to a unique string.  I want the variable myMask in main to reflect the change made in the last mouse event handler.  Unfortunately, myMask is never changed in main. Why?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here are two extracts from OpenCV and a portion of the code:

§ MouseCallback
typedef void(* cv::MouseCallback) (int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *userdata)
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

Callback function for mouse events. see cv::setMouseCallback.

Parameters
event   one of the cv::MouseEventTypes constants.
x   The x-coordinate of the mouse event.
y   The y-coordinate of the mouse event.
flags   one of the cv::MouseEventFlags constants.
userdata    The optional parameter.

§ setMouseCallback()
void cv::setMouseCallback   (   const String &  winname,
MouseCallback   onMouse,
void *  userdata = 0
)
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

Sets mouse handler for the specified window.

Parameters
winname Name of the window.
onMouse Callback function for mouse events. See OpenCV samples on how to specify and use the callback.
userdata    The optional parameter passed to the callback.

```
# BW MouseCallback funcs
myMask = 'none'  # Mask to apply
# One Callback func per window
# BW none Callback
def mouseHandler( event, x, y, flags, userdata ):
    if event == 1:   # cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN
        userdata = 'none'
# BW halfBlack Callback
def mouseHandlerHB( event, x, y, flags, userdata ):
    if event == 1:   # cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN
        userdata = 'halfBlack'
# BW centreWhite Callback
def mouseHandlerCW( event, x, y, flags, userdata ):
    if event == 1:   # cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN
        userdata = 'centreWhite'
# BW bitAnd Callback
def mouseHandlerBA( event, x, y, flags, userdata ):
    if event == 1:   # cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN
        userdata = 'bitAnd'
# BW bitOr Callback
def mouseHandlerBO( event, x, y, flags, userdata ):
    if event == 1:   # cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN
        userdata = 'bitOr'
# BW bitXor Callback
def mouseHandlerBX( event, x, y, flags, userdata ):
    if event == 1:   # cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN
        userdata  = 'bitXor'
# BW setMouseCallbacks, tie Callback func to a window
cv2.setMouseCallback( 'piCamR', mouseHandler, myMask )
cv2.setMouseCallback( 'halfBlack', mouseHandlerHB, myMask )
cv2.setMouseCallback( 'centreWhite', mouseHandlerCW, myMask )
cv2.setMouseCallback( 'bitAnd', mouseHandlerBA, myMask )
cv2.setMouseCallback( 'bitOr', mouseHandlerBO, myMask )
cv2.setMouseCallback( 'bitXor', mouseHandlerBX, myMask )

while True:

    # Grab a frame
    ret, frame1 = cam.read()
    print(myMask)
    # BW Apply mask?
    if myMask != 'none':
        if myMask == 'halfBlack':
            frame1 = cv2.bitwise_and( frame1, frame1, mask = halfBlack )
        elif myMask == 'centreWhite':
            frame1 = cv2.bitwise_and( frame1, frame1, mask = centreWhite )
        elif myMask == 'bitAnd':
            frame1 = cv2.bitwise_and( frame1, frame1, mask = bitAnd )
        elif myMask == 'bitOr':
            frame1 = cv2.bitwise_and( frame1, frame1, mask = bitOr )
        else:  # myMask == bitXor
            frame1 = cv2.bitwise_and( frame1, frame1, mask = bitXor )
    # Show frame and position
    cv2.imshow( 'piCamR', frame1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to modify a global variable, and these are two possibilities (I'll write the snippets below for 1 handler, and you just need to replicate):

1. Always modify the same global:

```py
myMask = 'none'
def mouseHandler(event, x, y, flags):  # in this case, no need for userdata
  global myMask  # this is important
  if event == 1:
    myMask = 'none'
cv2.setMouseCallback('piCamR', mouseHandler)
```

2. Modify a global variable by name:

```py
myMask = 'none'
def mouseHandler(event, x, y, flags, userdata: str):  # userdata would be a string
  if event == 1:
    globals()[userdata] = 'none'
cv2.setMouseCallback('piCamR', mouseHandler, 'myMask')  # pass the variable name as str
```

3. Pass an object with the mask:

```py
class MyMasks:
  def __init__(self):
    self.myMask = 'none'

def mouseHandler(event, x, y, flags, userdata: MyMasks):  # userdata would be an instance of MyMasks
    if event == 1:
        userdata.myMask = 'none'

mymasks = MyMasks()  # instantiate your masks
cv2.setMouseCallback('piCamR', mouseHandler, mymasks)  # pass the object
```

Comment: Your 1. suggestion was my original version.  However, as I'm more of a c programmer I am opposed to the use of global variables. That is why I am trying to rewriting the program without their use.

Comment: @MarkHache In your snippet, `myMask` *is* a global, unless there is something missing before that other than the imports.

Comment: You are correct.  I guess I am trying to pass by reference, rather than by global.  Perhaps that is my problem, I'm trying to get python to act like c.

Comment: @MarkHache An alternative is to use an object in which the mask is an attribute. Passing the object and changing the attribute works as well. I'll update the answer with this 3rd option. Consider upvoting if you find the answer useful.

Comment: Thank-you.  Your third option worked a charm.

Comment: Option 3 is the way to go in situations where a global is not appropriate